# Sqlite sum time

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a column that contained time duration of events. 
It it formatted as 'h:mm:ss'
I found the function strftime - but according to the manual, it requires the  format 'hh:mm:ss'
can someone tell me how i can sum up the duration **without recreating the sql table**?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
with t as (
  select '4:02:01' as v
  union all
  select '9:30:12'
  union all
  select '2:14:00'
),
diff as (
 select sum(strftime('%s', '0'||v) - strftime('%s', '00:00:00')) as v
 from t
)

select (v/3600) || ' hours, ' || (v%3600/60) ||' minutes, '
       || (v%60) || ' seconds.'
from diff
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2SNbFYQv2zYiCE4gw5bhzi/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time()` and `strftime()`:

```
select 
  time(sum(
    strftime('%s', case length(timecolumn) when 7 then '0' else '' end || timecolumn) 
    - strftime('%s','00:00:00')), 
   'unixepoch') totaltime
from tablename
```

The result time sum will be in format `hh:mm:ss`.